# How do I set the value 'title' on the td?

Tags: jquery

I want to set 'title' on each 'td' under the 'createdRow : function(..)'

```
td1 - 1
td2 -'company1'
td3 - 'bu1'
..
```

So, I need the result below.

```
<tr>
 <td title='1'>1</td>
 <td title='company1'>company1</td>
 ..
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it's using [tag:datatables].  Is that the case?  Please include the relevant *code*, not an image.

Answer (score -2):

This may help you

```js
$('td').each(()=>{$(this).attr('title',$(this).text().trim())})
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to use the selector `$('td')` in the `createdRow` function as that selector will match all `td` cells, including those updated previously in other calls to that function.

Comment: Small change to either `$(row).find("td")....` or `$(tds)...` (no quotes)  given the parameters in OPs image - *but* that definition conflicts with [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) definition, so it's unclear exactly what OP is using.

Comment: Your edit is still incorrect I'm afraid - as you're using an arrow function `this` will refer to the outer scope, not the current `td` within the `each()` loop.

Comment: I tried this and it work. 
`createdRow: function(row, tds, rowIdx, ths){ 
$(row).children().each(
(i, element, n) => {$(element).attr('title', element.innerHTML);}); } `

Thank you all !